# SOLVED: Error making a Swap in UniswapV3

Tags: uniswap, web3.py, uniswapv3

First of all, sorry for my English.

Using `web3.py` [I managed to execute a swap from an "X" coin to WETH from a UniswapV3 pool](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf98530d2996ec4ac28acbe57926b55ed664cbe19e960af992de9ce6ee24ec62e). However, I miss an error when I try to execute a swap from WETH to an "X" coin. I don't know what I'm failing at, could you help me?

This is the code that I have:

```
def transactionUniswap(account_id, amountIn, amountOutMin, pairs):
    try:
        # Connection to ETH
        w3 = connectToWeb3()
        # Get all data
        amountIn = w3.toWei(amountIn, "ether")
        amountOutMin = w3.toWei(amountOutMin, "ether")
        contractUniswap = getContract(w3)
        account = getAccount(w3, account_id)
        gasPrice = getGasPrice(w3)
        nonce = getNonce(w3, account_id)
        privateKey = getPrivateKey(account_id)

        abi = get_abi()

        import time
        # Calculate timestamp
        current_ts = int(time.time()) + (30*60)

        params_function = {
            'tokenIn':pairs[0],
            'tokenOut':pairs[1],
            'fee':3000,
            'recipient':account.address,
            'deadline':current_ts,
            'amountIn':amountIn,
            'amountOutMinimum':amountOutMin,
            'sqrtPriceLimitX96':0
        }

        # Create the transaction
        calls = []
        swap = contractUniswap.encodeABI( fn_name = 'exactInputSingle', args=[params_function])


        # checks if token to swap is WETH
        value = 0 if pairs[0] != '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2' else amountIn
        

        txArgs = {
            "to":contractUniswap.address,
            "from": account.address,
            "data":swap,
            "gas":200000,
            "gasPrice":int(gasPrice),
            "nonce":nonce,
            "value":value
        }
        
        # Sign the transaction
        signed_tx = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(txArgs, privateKey)

        send_transaction = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)



        return True
    

    except Exception as e:
        raise e
        return e
```

And here you can check the hash, with the input data and more:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc495901215f34af3b92bdd69df0686fe8ae8e7a5f14937862faf5690c2f07099

**SOLUTION**

At the end, I found a library called [uniswap-python](https://uniswap-python.com/) that makes the swap really fast and easy, with only few lines of code:

```
from uniswap import Uniswap
        uniswap = Uniswap(address=YOUR_ADDRESS_ACCOUNT, private_key=_YOUR_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY, version=CAN_BE_3_2_1, provider=YOUR_NODE)
```

Comment: I looked at the tx, your X token raised an error ""ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance". So you need to approve the router first.

Comment: How exactly? Making a multicall? Or how?

Thanks you so much for your answer

Comment: You need to make a transaction before the swap, with `to=token.address` and as `data` the ABI-encoded `approve(router.address, max_uint256)`.

Comment: @MiguelPayá Please, add the solution as an answer. So the question can be marked as resolved.

Comment: @Ismael done! Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

At the end, I found a library called [uniswap-python](https://uniswap-python.com/) that makes the swap really fast and easy, with only few lines of code:

```
from uniswap import Uniswap
        uniswap = Uniswap(address=YOUR_ADDRESS_ACCOUNT, private_key=_YOUR_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY, version=CAN_BE_3_2_1, provider=YOUR_NODE)
```